# Building OpenCV using CMake problems

Tags: opencv, cmake

For using CUDA, I need to compile OpenCV. I'm using CMake and OpenCV 3 sources. I do not get any errors when clicking und "Generate" in CMake. Then I compile the OpenCV.sln solution for Win64 using Visual Studio (I selected the right visual studio version). I do not get any errors when compiling.
But I do know what to include; normally, there is "opencv" and "opencv2" in the include folder. But this does not exist.

My opencv folder after compiling:

[image]

My include folder:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Includes located in sources folder, not in build folder (if you did not Build INSTALL project).

Comment: Thanks, I had to build INSTALL project!